# Why is extracting a column from a pandas DataFrame as a list and performing list comprehension faster than using the map function?

Tags: python, pandas

While using pandas DataFrames, I have observed that extracting a column as a list, using list comprehension and then reinserting it back into the DataFrame is faster than using the map function.

To test this, I created a two column data frame, one with numbers from 0 to 999 and the next with the squares of those numbers. Then, I add a cubes column whose values are computed in two different ways.

#### Setup

The data frame is created. Two copies are made of the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[x for x in range(1000)],'squares':[x*x for x in range(1000)]})

df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()
```

#### Case 1

Using the map function:

```
%%timeit
# using map
df3['cubes'] = np.nan
df3['cubes'] = df3.numbers.map(lambda x: x**3)
```

When I ran this in Jupyter notebook, time taken was

> 1.31 ms ± 7.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#### Case 2

Extracting the column as a list and then using list comprehension whose result is reinserted into the data frame:

```
%%timeit
df4['cubes'] = np.nan
L = list(df4.numbers)
df4['cubes'] = [x**3 for x in L]
```

When I ran this in Jupyter notebook, time taken was

> 1.07 ms ± 3.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Simply put, `map` is not built for vectorised operation. Try `%timeit df.numbers ** 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas functions are not silver bullets. Some of them are implemented to offer a wide range of functionality on varying inputs, and this involves many overheads. Additionally, many of them are written in python, and there are many layers of functionality to pass through before you get your end result.

A list comprehension, on the other hand, is implemented in pure C, and is optimised to be *fast*.

The ugly `map` version you've used looks like this:

```
temp = []
f = lambda x: x**3
for v in df3.numbers:
    temp.append(f(v))

df3['cubes'] = temp
```

Plus a lot more overheads. This isn't the case for *every* type of input, though. For example, `map` with a `Series` can be *extremely* fast.

Do keep in mind, that the *fastest* way of doing this is -

```
%timeit df.numbers ** 3
10000 loops, best of 3: 179 µs per loop
```

Which happens to be faster than *both* loopy solutions. In general, avoid lambdas and loops when working with pandas.